Unable to see databases in psql even though I can see them in PGDATA: main/base folder
I had issue with postgres PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record which caused me to run pg_resetwal. I was okay with losing whatever data was there in WAL.
Now after running that I can only see 4 databases even though I have several in main/base directory.
I have double/triple checked the datadir path is correct. I have checked it in postgres.conf as well as on psql.
I have created a new cluster and set the part to the data dir, still it didnot work. This issue is for users too. I had many users now I just have 2. Same with extension, it doesn't show the extension I had installed.
How do I recover from this.

Sounds like this database has been through several botched recovery attempts.  Do you have clean backups?  Do you have the log file from the last time the database was running correctly?

@jjanes i ran pg_resetwal hoping it corrects it, other than that nothing. I saw an error in log called global/pg_filenode.map not found

I don't see how this could happen, as for all extra databases to be missing just due to pg_resetwal would require that there were no checkpoints done between the creations and the pg_resetwal. But creating databases itself triggers checkpoints to happen. So how could multiple different ones be missing?  But anyway, your error message sounds like the filesystem itself has become unreliable, at which point there is not telling what might happen.  Maybe the file system has found zombie blocks containing allegedly overwritten data, and then revived them at the expense of the real data.
